# Problem in In-App purchase-consumable model

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a non-consumable in-app purchase item and now I want to create a consumable in-app purchase item by which  a user to buy it every time by using In-App purchase. Now what will have to change in following code in different model:-

**in InApp purchase manager.m:**

```
@implementation InAppPurchaseManager


//@synthesize purchasableObjects;
//@synthesize storeObserver;
@synthesize proUpgradeProduct;
@synthesize productsRequest;


//BOOL featureAPurchased;
//BOOL featureBPurchased;

//static InAppPurchaseManager* _sharedStoreManager; // self

- (void)dealloc {

    //[_sharedStoreManager release];
    //[storeObserver release];
    [super dealloc];
}




- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.comp_name.iWorkOut1" ];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];

    // we will release the request object in the delegate callback
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    //NSArray *products = response.products;
    //proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain]: nil;

    if (proUpgradeProduct)
        {
            NSLog(@"Product title: %@", proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
            NSLog(@"Product description: %@", proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
            NSLog(@"Product price: %@", proUpgradeProduct.price);
            NSLog(@"Product id:%@", proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
        }

    /*for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
        {
            NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
        }*/

     //finally release the reqest we alloc/init’ed in requestProUpgradeProductData
    [productsRequest release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}



#pragma -
#pragma Public methods

/* call this method once on startup*/

- (void)loadStore
{
    /* restarts any purchases if they were interrupted last time the app was open*/
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    /* get the product description (defined in early sections)*/
    [self requestProUpgradeProductData];
}

/* call this before making a purchase*/

- (BOOL)canMakePurchases
{


    return [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments];
}

/* kick off the upgrade transaction*/

- (void)purchaseProUpgrade
{
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"1212121"];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}
#pragma -
#pragma Purchase helpers

/* saves a record of the transaction by storing the receipt to disk*/

- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if ([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId])
        {
            /* save the transaction receipt to disk*/
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:transaction.transactionReceipt forKey:@"proUpgradeTransactionReceipt" ];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
}

/* enable pro features*/

- (void)provideContent:(NSString *)productId
{
    if ([productId isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId])
        {
            /* enable the pro features*/
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"isProUpgradePurchased" ];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        }
}


- (void)finishTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction wasSuccessful:(BOOL)wasSuccessful
{
    // /* remove the transaction from the payment queue.*/
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];

        NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:transaction, @"transaction" , nil];
        if (wasSuccessful)
        {



            /* send out a notification that we’ve finished the transaction*/
                  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];


        }
        else
        {

            /* send out a notification for the failed transaction*/
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object:self userInfo:userInfo];
        }
    }



- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}    

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}    

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
        {
            /* error!*/
            [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:NO];
        }
    else
        {
            /* this is fine, the user just cancelled, so don’t notify*/
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];



        }   
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
        {
            switch (transaction.transactionState)
            {
                    case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                    [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                    break;
                    case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                    [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                    break;
                    case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                    [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                    break;
                    default:
                    break;
            }
        }
}






@end
```

in SKProduct.m:-

```
@implementation SKProduct (LocalizedPrice)
- (NSString *)localizedPrice
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:self.priceLocale];
    NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:self.price];
    [numberFormatter release];
    return formattedString;
}
```

Comment: "Here is all my code please fix it" isn't going to work. Read the docs, figure it out yourself, if you have a *specific* problem, ask here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at [InventoryKit](http://blog.migrantstudios.com/2011/01/21/introducing-inventorykit-for-ios-developers/), which provides support for non-consumable, consumable and subscription in app purchases, and is open source.